# Computing symbolic form of trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, special-functions, series-expansion

To calculate symbolically this integrale

$$I(s)= \int\limits_0^{\pi/2} \dfrac{\cos t}{\sin^2 t-R^2} \; e^{-s/\cos t}\; dt$$

which has already been asked  [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/172122/computing-symbolic-form-of-integral), @yarchik has suggested to me to post it in a separate thread.

So in this post I have proceeded differently. I have developed the integrant for R<<1, I got:

$$I(s)= \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}R^{2n}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos t }{\sin^{2n+2}t}e^{-s/\cos t}dt$$

or

```
 Sum[R^(2n)Assuming[s>0,Integrate[Exp[-s/Cos[t]]Cos[t]/Sin[t]^(2n+2),{t,0,Pi/2},PrincipalValue->True]],{n,0,Infinity}]
```

so the integration of this series gives:

```
Sum[ConditionalExpression[(R^(2n)Gamma[-(1/2)-n] MeijerG[{{},{1/2-n}},{{0,1/2,1},{}},s^2/4])/(2Sqrt[\[Pi]]),Re[n]<-(1/2)],{n,0,Infinity},Assumptions ->R<= 1].
```

The problem is that Mathematica can't calculate this `Sum` which represents in fact my integral.

Please, any ideas.

Comment: There is a $\frac{1}{t-t_0}$ singularity at $t_0=\arcsin R$ in the integration region (assuming $0<R<1$). The integral is meaningless are written.

Comment: so the sum is wrong or what @AccidentalFourierTransform?

Comment: The sum is meaningless too. It probably diverges; and, if it doesn't, it would be a sort of regularisation of the integral, not equal to it. (Because the integral doesn't exist). Note that the terms in the sum have a $t^{-2n-2}$ divergence at the origin, so the integral doesn't converge...)

Comment: But according to @Mariusz Iwaniuk calculation, integral exist.

Comment: No, according to Mariusz the *principal value* of the integral exists. So the regularised integral exists, if anything. But Taylor expansion doesn't commute with taking the principal value (in general), so there is no guarantee that the series is a meaningful operation. And, again, the different terms in the sum are divergent: the integral has a $t^{-2n-2}$ singularity. MMA tells you explicitly that the integral exists iff `Re[n]<-(1/2)`, which is not the case here. It seems that you may work with the analytical continuation to $n\in\mathbb N$, though. Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much. So do you have please any idea about calculating the convolution product in the end of @Mariusz Iwaniuk calculation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77100/discussion-between-betatron-and-accidentalfouriertransform).

Comment: Plotting the function might help.  `Manipulate[
 Plot[Cos[t]/(Sin[t]^2 - R^2) Exp[-s/Cos[t]], {t, 0, \[Pi]/2}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-ymax, ymax}}, 
  Ticks -> {(\[Pi]/8) {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, Automatic}],
 {{s, 1}, 0, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{R, 0.5}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{ymax, 10}, 0, 100, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 TrackedSymbols :> {s, R, ymax}]`.

Comment: @JimB Thank you for the plot.